# Blender mesh not smooth

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm quite new to blender so I can imagine that this problem might be easy to solve but I've been searching for a few days without any result..

I'm modeling this car in blender and see tried out the subdivision surface tool to make the model smooth. When doing this, the mesh shows hard edges/sharp lines (see rear wheel arch and front fender) while nothing is creased. I also checked for dubble vertices or some familliar issues I used to have in Alias Speedform.

What could be the problem? Hopefully someone can help me out!

THANKS!!
[image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like mismatched normal directions. Go to edit mode, select all, then `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`

Comment: Use smooth modifier instead.

Comment: And apply the scale. It is very important. In object mode hit ctrl+a and select scale. Because you have a negtive z value, the face normals will be flipped, so recalculate the normals after it. Watch out for the uniform scale any time, if you rescale the meshes in object mode, you will have a bad time.

Comment: recalculate outside worked, Thanks!!